# sharepoint quick parts document property not syncing after 2010 to 2013 migration

Tags: 2013, quick-parts

We have thousands of word documents in SP 2010 in various library works perfectly as part of Quick Parts implementation. Those documents are migrated to SP 2013 (Metalogix's Content Matrix). Now when I open the document they are not syncing with the metadata. The libraries are identical between SP 2010 and 2013 (same content types, same number of columns, etc.).

Is there a powershell or tool that can refresh all of the words documents. URGENT ISSUE. CAN ANYONE PLEASE SUGGEST SOMETHING?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is a third party tool to do a file compare between the libraries. This particular tool does allow for a trial period with full functionality and will make sure that they are the same bit for bit. The only issue is that if the meta data is not embedded in the files themselves, it will not do anything with it.

Not sure if it will do everything you need, but take a look at Beyond Compare 4.